# Which JSTL URL should I reference in my JSPs?

Tags: jsp, jstl, uri, taglib

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a JSP.
I'm using Tomcat 6.0.18, and I'd like to use the latest version of JSTL.

What version of JSTL should I use, and which URL goes with which version of JSTL?

I'm getting this error

"According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute key does not accept any expressions"

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

I'll just say I had this working, but I want to switch the JSTL jar file that has the TLD files in the jar file. (instead of having to deploy them somewhere in the web application and define the references in web.xml).

Comment: So this is a duplicate of a question, but my "duplicate" was posted 7 years ago and the one it duplicated was posted 4 years ago. That makes a lot of sense....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

More on this topic [here](http://faq.javaranch.com/view?JstlTagLibDefinitions)